# JavaScript - get href attribute value via DOM traversal

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am writing a client-side JavaScript code and I have to retrieve the URL from the `href` attribute.

I have already travelled the DOM to a point where:

```js
document.getElementById('something').getElementsByTagName('td')[3];
```

Which outputs:

```html
<td><a href="http://example.com"></a></td>
```

From there, how do I get `http://example.com`?

I tried using `.getAttribute("href")`, but I got `null`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do like this `document.querySelector('#something td:nth-child(3) a').href`

Comment: I would say so you are missing something. Ever hear of a `td` (table cell), having a `href` attribute? No? Me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

I think I should point out (since this has been accepted), what @LGSon had put in the comments and @hev1 has put in their answer, that this should be handled in a more elegant way than simply calling `getElement` on multiple DOM elements.

Here is a proposed (and much nicer) version of the call to get the `href` value:

> ```
> document.querySelector('#something td:nth-child(3) a').href;
> ```

### Original Answer

The `href` property exists on the anchor tag (`<a>`) which is a child of the `<td>` element. You will need to grab the anchor by using something like the DOM `children` property like so:

```
tdElement = document.getElementById('something').getElementsByTagName('td')[3];
anchor = tdElement.children[0];
anchor.getAttribute("href");
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...i just converted all into a one line query...thanks a lot.

Comment: @hnvasa It is a really bad solution to nest several `document.getElement*` calls like that, so I strongly recommend to go with `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I would definitely agree with @LGSon. But for a "quick and dirty solution", if you know the `<td>` element only has one child and it is the anchor you are looking for, this will work. But it should be handled more gracefully, like with a `querySelector` call.

Answer (score 4):

The `td` tag does not have `href` attribute (no table cell has this attribute); its child `a` tag does.

You can get the `a` tag inside the table cell with a query selector from which you can get the `href` attribute.

```
document.getElementById('something').getElementsByTagName('td')[3].querySelector('a').href;
```

Or you can combine the whole selection into a query selector.

```
document.querySelector('#something td:nth-child(3) a').href;
```

```html
<table id="something">
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td><a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a></td>
</table>
<script>
console.log(document.querySelector('#something td:nth-child(3) a').href);
</script>
```

Comment: @hnvasa No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Purely using `js` (not `jquery`) and if you want to specifically continue from when you have selected the `td` tag you desire:

`td.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href`

`td` being the `td` element that was returned from your example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
let x = document.getElementById("test").href;
console.log(x);
</script>
```

You can also get by class or tag but you will have to loop through the array, and that could be a lot of  tags on a page.

also,

```
document.getElementById('something').getElementsByTagName('td')[3].firstElementChild.href
```